# Excel conditional format by finding text in column

Tags: excel

I would like to format some data in excel only if the text "hello" appears anywhere in the same column. That is, there should be at least one cell in the same column whose entire content is the text "hello".

In the "format values if this formula is true" box when conditional formatting, I have pasted this:

="COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""C"",FALSE),""hello"")>0"

I have checked it works as a formula in the sheet, but it does not work as the formula for conditional formatting

Is there a way to achieve this?

The background is I am formatting a pivot table, and don't have any control over where the data will sit on my sheet, and no option to use VBA.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using `INDIRECT`? `=COUNTIF(C:C,"hello")>0` should work if you are looking in column `C`

Comment: See if you can do a VLookup using the range of your pivot table.  Like =VLookup("hello",$C:$C,1,false).  If that works, your Conditional formula could be that inside IfError() inside Not().

Comment: Thank you both. Found solution, which I will post. cybernetic.nomad - the indirect("C",FALSE) is to get a reference to the current column

Answer (score 0):

The formula should be this, and then it works

=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("C",FALSE),"hello")>0